# Will a 10mm eyepiece with a barlow 2x produce the same result as a 5mm eyepiece?

Tags: eyepiece, barlow

So I have been wondering if a barlow (say 2x) will produce the same result of a half eyepiece....
So would a 10mm with a 2X Barlow produce the same result as a 5mm? (Assuming the FOV is the same on the 10mm and the 5mm)....

Since I dont have any combination that would be "equivalent" I cant test the result

Comment: This site may be of service in the future: https://astronomy.tools/calculators/field_of_view/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a Barlow effectively increases the focal length of the telescope, leaving other factors the same.  So, the magnification will be the same as if you were using a 5mm eyepiece.

However, a cheap 10mm eyepiece usually has better eye relief and apparent field of view than a cheap 5mm.  So, you are actually better off with the Barlow than getting a 5mm.

The only downsides are you increase the number of surfaces (and thus loose light to reflections), and there might be some issues with focus if you have short focuser travel.

Comment: I keep thinking that there's got to be a catch somewhere, somehow. Ignoring reflections and chromatic and other aberrations due to imperfect optics, we can always get a boost in eye relief by using a Barlow with a lower magnification eyepiece without sacrificing anything else? That seems like an actually really good reason to use a Barlow lens!

Comment: @uhoh the main catch is that the Barlow costs money.  If it were free, they'd integrate it into every eyepiece.

Comment: @GregMiller IIRC some high end eye pieces do include a built in barlow; used with variable powers so they can gain economies of scale by reusing the same fancy optics for multiple eye pieces within a single series.